# curl changes the URI in the authorization header for digest behind proxy

Tags: apache, http, curl, digest-authentication

I am trying to use curl for a http request.
I have to use it behind a enterprise proxy server. The remote host uses digest authentication.

I am using the following curl command.

```bash
curl -x "http://proxy_username:proxy_pass@proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080" -L -X GET "https://remote-host.something.com:443/tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet" --digest -u digest_auth_user:digest_auth_pass -v -k
```

But I get 400 bad request from apache httpd. The full output from curl is

```
*   Trying proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080...
* Connected to proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx (proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8080 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to remote-host.something.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'proxy_username'
* Server auth using Digest with user 'digest_auth_user'
> CONNECT remote-host.something.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: remote-host.something.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic <redacted>
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Via:HTTP/1.1 s_proxy_nrt
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server auth using Digest with user 'digest_auth_user'
> GET /tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet HTTP/1.1
> Host: remote-host.something.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Server: Cisco Umbrella
< Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 02:52:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 190
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: swg_https_a2bc=1; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 14-Feb-23 03:02:03 GMT; domain=remote-host.something.com; SameSite=None; Secure
< Location: https://remote-host.something.com/tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1
< Via: HTTP/1.1 s_proxy_nrt
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://remote-host.something.com/tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1'
* Found bundle for host: 0x1a0ed47d970 [serially]
* Re-using existing connection #0 with proxy proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx
* Connected to proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx (proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'digest_auth_user'
> GET /tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: remote-host.something.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 02:52:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 381
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="https_transfer", nonce="redacted", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
< Via: HTTP/1.1 m_proxy_nrt
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://remote-host.something.com/tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1'
* Found bundle for host: 0x1a0ed47d970 [serially]
* Re-using existing connection #0 with proxy proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx
* Connected to proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx (proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'digest_auth_user'
> GET /tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: remote-host.something.com
> Authorization: Digest username="digest_auth_user",realm="https_transfer",nonce="redacted",uri="/tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1",cnonce="redacted",nc=00000001,algorithm=MD5,response="redacted",qop="redacted"
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 02:52:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 226
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
< Via: HTTP/1.1 m_proxy_nrt
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host proxyIp.xxx.xxx.xxx left intact
```

Is the server side, I get the following in httpd log.

```
[auth_digest:error] [pid 3052:tid 1928] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx] AH01786: uri mismatch - </tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet?swg_a2bc=1> does not match request-uri </tomcat_servlet/UploadServlet>
```

Indeed, cURL is adding some query it is getting from the proxy server in the authentication header.

Settings of my httpd

```
<Location /tomcat_servlet>
 ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/tomcat_servlet
 ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/tomcat_servlet
 AuthType Digest
 AuthName https_transfer
 AuthUserFile ${SRVROOT}/conf/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

How do I use cURL in this situation? Or should I change some settings in the httpd side?

Comment: try replacing the `username:pass@` scheme with `--proxy-user 'username:pass'`

Comment: Tried `--proxy-user`, did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

it is your Cisco Proxy that for some cause (unknown to me) switched its own cookie from PUT to GET method triggering your server to complain about that unkown query parameter ... look at the 307 response!
You should contact your proxy admin and ask him for support, because I do not think, you have a chance to fix this issue on client side.
workaround (if possible): make the server ignore unknown params.